# What pattern should I use for aggregating different types of events in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to use Kafka for my event handling, but I'm struggling a bit to understand what pattern I should use.

My use case is this:

- One consumer waits for one type of event.
- When that event is processed, the same consumer need to produce several different types of events to different topics using a subset of that incoming events properties.
- Then once all of those events are consumed (the order doesn't matter) by their respective consumer I need to know it and send the aggregated response to another topic.

I've looked at building a Saga state machine, event aggregator, fan in/fan out and scatter/gather as possible solutions, but I'm not sure what would be the best approach. Kafka Streams?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75687977/what-pattern-should-i-use-for-aggregating-different-types-of-events-in-apache-ka "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Regardless of patterns, Kafka Streams does the first two bullets perfectly fine using filter function. What exactly do you mean by "send the aggregated response back." Back to what?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated the question to say "to another topic" instead of back. My bad.

Yeah, Streams seem to do the job, unfortunately I discovered that there isn't a reliable lib for Kafka Streams for .NET, so I'm out of luck. Maybe ksqldb instead, any opinon about that?

Comment: I don't have .NET experience (I believe I found a project on Github for porting Kafka Streams to C#)... ksqlDB can work, yes, but not as flexible

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need a routing service that listens for completion of the various sub processes and then posts a "completed" message.

This means that process is holding the state in memory while it waits, which seems problematic but should be fine. Kafka's non-messagequeuey hang on to all the messages approach should work well here; as you can loop back from the start of all the "done" and"complete" messages to rebuild the current state in the event of a crash.